# MYSQL select based on matching two condition for same column

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT  `product_id` 
FROM    `attribute_value` 
WHERE   `spec_group_id` = 2 
AND     `product_id` = 1 
AND     `attribute_value` IN('samsung','56')
```

for the following data:

```
attribute_value_id   attribute_id   attribute_value   product_id   spec_group_id
1                    1              samsung           1            2
2                    2              55                1            2
3                    5              door-in-door      1            2
```

I need to get the product id only if it attribute value matches both samsung and 55.
how to write a select query?

In my query If i change the attribute value as 56 then too it will get the product id.

Comment: It is difficult to read your question.  Please format the tabular data by adding four spaces to the start of each line.

Comment: Don't use `in`, that is for either, use an `=` and use two additional parameters. Although I don't see how `attribute_value` can be `55` and `samsung` at the same time

Comment: The answer is in your question, replace and attribute_value to the field name.

Comment: Actually this is for my ecommerce site. I need to fetch the samsung product with 55 discount.It is similar to filter function in ecommerce site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need aggregation and the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM attribute_value 
WHERE spec_group_id = 2 AND attribute_value IN ('samsung', '56')
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query for the IN-operator to first select all `product_id` with `samsung` as `attribute_value` and then select the ones where `attribute_value` is `55`. Here is an example:

```
SELECT  `product_id` 
FROM    `attribute_value` 
WHERE   `spec_group_id` = 2 
AND     `product_id` IN(SELECT `product_id` FROM `attribute_value` WHERE `attribute_value` = 'samsung') 
AND     `attribute_value` = 55
```

Comment: This will work if there is two condition.In case of multiple condition how to write query.The query will be dynamic based on filter options selected.It may go like samsung ,red,55,etc...

Comment: Well, then it will get pretty messy. Of course you could just add sub-queries to the sub-queries for every further option selected. But i would really consider changing the data-base-structure to have unique `product_id` with a comma-sperated field with all attributes. Or use a view.

Comment: okiee thanks. Will change the structure and try to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_eav;

CREATE TABLE my_eav 
(attribute_value_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,attribute_id INT NOT NULL
,attribute_value VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,product_id INT NOT NULL
,UNIQUE KEY(product_id,attribute_id)
);

INSERT INTO my_eav VALUES
(1,1,'samsung',1),
(2,2,'55',1),
(3,5,'door-in-door',1);     

CREATE VIEW v_eav AS
SELECT product_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute_id = 1 THEN attribute_value END) make
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute_id = 2 THEN attribute_value END) size
  FROM my_eav
 GROUP 
    BY product_id;
    
SELECT * FROM v_eav WHERE make = 'samsung' AND size = '55';

+------------+---------+------+
| product_id | make    | size |
+------------+---------+------+
|          1 | samsung | 55   |
+------------+---------+------+
```

Perhaps it's obvious that the view isn't strictly necessary to achieve the same thing.